# How do you kick off an Azure ML experiment based on a scheduler?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, cortana-intelligence

I created an experiment within Azure ML Studio and published as a web service. I need the experiment to run nightly or possible several times a day. I currently have azure mobile services and azure web jobs as part of the application and need to create an endpoint to retrieve data from the published web service. Obviously, the whole point is to make sure I have updated data.

I see answers like use azure data factory but I need specifics as in how to actually set up the scheduler.

I explain my dilemma further @ https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e7126c6e-b43e-474a-b461-191f0e27eb74/scheduling-a-machine-learning-experiment-and-publishing-nightly?forum=AzureDataFactory

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-retrain-models-programmatically/

Comment: yes I have. helps a little but I am looking for details.

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify what you mean by "experiment to run nightly"?

When you publish the experiment as a web service, it should give you and api key and the endpoint to consume the service. From that point on you should be able to call this api with the key, and it would return the result processing it tru the model you've initially trained. So all you have to do is to do the call from your web/mobile/desktop etc application in the desired times.

If the issue is to retrain the data model nightly, to improve the prediction, then this is a different process. That was only available tru the UI only, now you can achieve this programmatically by using the retraining api.

Kindly find the usage of this [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-retrain-models-programmatically/).

Hope this helps!
Mert